# Упрощение многочлена (скобки без вложенности)

Tags: математика, любой-язык, sympy, интерполяция

Нахожу многочлен Лагранжа. На выходе получаю выражение вида:

*L(x) = - a<sub>0</sub>(x - x<sub>1</sub>)(x - x<sub>2</sub>)(x - x<sub>3</sub>)(x - x<sub>4</sub>)(x - x<sub>5</sub>) + a1(x - x<sub>0</sub>)(x - x<sub>2</sub>)(x - x<sub>3</sub>)(x - x<sub>4</sub>)(x - x<sub>5</sub>) - ... - a5(x - x<sub>0</sub>)(x - x<sub>1</sub>)(x - x<sub>2</sub>)(x - x<sub>3</sub>)(x - x<sub>4</sub>)*

Необходимо привести к каноническому виду:

*L(x) = A<sub>0</sub>* * *x<sup>5</sup> + ... + A<sub>4</sub>* * *x + A<sub>5</sub>*

Необходимо реализовать это программно.

В связи с чем вопрос: есть ли где готовые реализации подобного кода? На **любом** языке. Мне бы посмотреть разобраться.

Уверен, что задача легко решаема, но буду рад любой реализации. Преподаватель внезапно решил, что ручной вариант его не устраивает и надо программно, ещё и сроки небольшие, а голова и без того забита вовсю курсовой.

**UPD:** Пролистайте до конца - там есть моя версия готовой программы.
Или нажмите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646229/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/647378#647378).

Comment: то есть данный вопрос является просьбой поискать решение в сети ?

Comment: http://vpaste.net/FMMSd :)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor я искал решения в сети, меня кидало на математические форумы либо для 6 класса (раскрытие скобок), либо по теории интерполяции. Все ссылки подразумевают ручное вычисления и ни намёка на программу. =(

Comment: @SeniorPomidor это скорее просьба в надежде, что у кого-то завалялся уже готовый вариант.. =/

Comment: Ну, ладно, когда-то я пофрилансил :) класс полинома, который умел полиномы складывать и умножать (делить не требовалось). Тут он бы прошел, но это писано на C++...

Comment: @Harry кидайте что есть, если не сложно. Лучше, чем ничего, попробую разобраться)

Comment: Сейчас поищу...

Comment: Вот тут - http://vpaste.net/a9mVc Но я соврал - в том смысле, что все равно писать нужно много - типа

    `using pd = Polynome<double>;
    pd L = pd{0} - pd{a0}*pd{1,-x1}*pd{1,-x2}*pd{1,-x3}*pd{1,-x4}*pd{1,-x5} + ....` - так что вряд ли это вам поможет...

Comment: @Harry спасибо, дома посмотрю. Может и смогу что-нибудь полезное для себя найти)

Comment: Для Python есть библиотека Sympy. Пример прямо сейчас привести не могу.

Comment: А в каком виде это выражение поступает? как строка или что? или прям в коде просто записано?

Comment: То, что вы хотите, называется "symbolic expansion". Может, знание термина поможет вам что-нибудь найти :) Программно это уже реализовано во всяких CAS (системах компьютерной алгебры). Если вам нужно развернуть конкретное выражение, можете попытать счастья у wxMaxima.

Comment: Не уверен, что понимаю какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить. Не могли бы вы описать немного более подробно что вы хотите получить?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Приведение многочлена к каноническому виду (раскрыть скобки и привести подобные слагаемые), чтобы можно было в последствии посчитать интеграл от выражения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для .Net существует библиотека под названием [MathNet.Symbolics](https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com). Конечно, её возможности намного меньше, чем у [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), но с вашей задачей тоже справится без проблем. `MathNet.Symbolics` написана на [F#](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp), но вы также можете её использовать на любом другом языке из семейства .Net.

К слову, если вы предпочитаете платформу .NET, то вы можете работать с `SymPy` при помощи [IronPython](http://ironpython.net)

---

Мне не очень нравится идея вручную задавать выражение, поэтому для удобства я написал простую функцию для его генерации

```
let test n = 
    let y = sprintf "A%i"
    let l i n = seq {
        for j in 0..n - 1 do
             if j <> i then
                yield sprintf "(x - x%i)" j
        }
    let p i = 
        let y' = y i 
        l i n
        |> String.concat "*"
        |> sprintf "%s*%s" y' 

    Array.init n p 
    |> String.concat "+"

open MathNet.Symbolics

let n = 4
let some = test n 

printfn "%s" some
//A0*(x - x1)*(x - x2)*(x - x3)+A1*(x - x0)*(x - x2)*(x - x3)+
//A2*(x - x0)*(x - x1)*(x - x3)+A3*(x - x0)*(x - x1)*(x - x2)

let expr = some |> Infix.parseOrUndefined
let exp = expr |> Algebraic.expand

exp
|> Infix.format
|> printfn "%s" 

(*
A0*x^3 + A1*x^3 + A2*x^3 + A3*x^3 - A1*x^2*x0 - A2*x^2*x0 - A3*x^2*x0 - A0*x^2*x1 - 
A2*x^2*x1 - A3*x^2*x1 + A2*x*x0*x1 + A3*x*x0*x1 - A0*x^2*x2 - A1*x^2*x2 - A3*x^2*x2 + 
A1*x*x0*x2 + A3*x*x0*x2 + A0*x*x1*x2 + A3*x*x1*x2 - A3*x0*x1*x2 - A0*x^2*x3 - A1*x^2*x3 - 
A2*x^2*x3 + A1*x*x0*x3 + A2*x*x0*x3 + A0*x*x1*x3 + A2*x*x1*x3 - A2*x0*x1*x3 + A0*x*x2*x3 + 
A1*x*x2*x3 - A1*x0*x2*x3 - A0*x1*x2*x3
*)
```

---

Раз уж речь зашла о полиномах Лагранжа приведу пример его вычисления по заданным узлам интерполяции (x, y).

В качестве тестовых значений возьмем соответствующие из статьи в [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B0) посвященной интерполяционному многочлену Лагранжа.

Функция для создания "шаблонного выражения":

```
let generate n = 
    let y = sprintf "y%i"
    let l i n = seq {
        for j in 0..n - 1 do
            if j <> i then
                yield sprintf "(x - x%i)/(x%i - x%i)" j i j
        }
    let p i = 
        l i n
        |> String.concat "*"
        |> sprintf "%s*%s" <| y i

    Array.init n p 
    |> String.concat "+"
```

задаем значения в виде словаря

```
let maps = 
    [
        "x0", -1.5; "x1", -0.75; "x2", 0.0; "x3",0.75; "x4",1.5 
        "y0", -14.1014; "y1",-0.931596;"y2", 0.0;"y3",0.931596; "y4",14.1014
    ] 
    |> Map.ofList
```

Заменяем переменные на значения пробегая по словарю

```
let poly =
    maps
    |> Map.fold
        (fun (acc : string) key value -> acc.Replace(key, string value))
        (generate n)
```

Преобразуем в выражение и переведем в более читабельный вид:

```
let ex = poly |> Infix.parseOrUndefined

ex
|> Algebraic.expand
|> Infix.format
|> printfn "%s"
```

В результате получим следующее выражение:

```
(-1.47747377777778)*x + 4.83484760493827*x^3
```

---

Если у вас возникнут какие-либо вопросы связанные с `F#` или с библиотекой `MathNet.Symbolics` не стесняйтесь спрашивать. Для удобства можете пинговать меня в [F# чате на SO](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f).

Comment: почувствовал себя феерическим идиотом, когда смог повторить ваш верхний пример на шарпе (получить разложенную строку) и вдруг понять, что не до конца пояснил задачу.. мне не просто строка упрощённая нужна, но и коэфициенты со степенями, чтобы использовать их для интегрирования выражения =D

Comment: к тому же, методы Infix и Algebraic отказались работать, когда я заменил Ai и xi на реальные числа double..

Answer (score 6):

## Python + sympy

```
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
xn = sympy.symarray('x', 3)  # от x_0 до x_2
an = sympy.symarray('a', 3)  # от a_0 до a_2

F = an[0]*(x-xn[0])*(x-xn[1])*(x-xn[2])+an[1]*(x-xn[0])*(x-xn[1])*(x-xn[2])+an[2]*(x-xn[0])*(x-xn[1])*(x-xn[2])

print(F.as_poly())
```

Результат:

`Poly(x**3*a_0 + x**3*a_1 + x**3*a_2 - x**2*a_0*x_0 - x**2*a_0*x_1 - x**2*a_0*x_2 - x**2*a_1*x_0 - x**2*a_1*x_1 - x**2*a_1*x_2 - x**2*a_2*x_0 - x**2*a_2*x_1 - x**2*a_2*x_2 + x*a_0*x_0*x_1 + x*a_0*x_0*x_2 + x*a_0*x_1*x_2 + x*a_1*x_0*x_1 + x*a_1*x_0*x_2 + x*a_1*x_1*x_2 + x*a_2*x_0*x_1 + x*a_2*x_0*x_2 + x*a_2*x_1*x_2 - a_0*x_0*x_1*x_2 - a_1*x_0*x_1*x_2 - a_2*x_0*x_1*x_2, x, a_0, a_1, a_2, x_0, x_1, x_2, domain='ZZ')`

Comment: Заметил ваш ответ только поздно ночью. Спасибо, посмотрю днём. Выглядит всё очень просто)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за помощь. Особенно @FoggyFinder и @insolor.

Выкладываю завершённый и рабочий вариант.
Программа по узлам и заданной функции (double f(double x){}) составляет многочлен Лагранжа, приводит его к каноническому виду и вычисляет определённый интеграл (работает, только для числовых значений).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MathNet.Symbolics;

namespace Polynom
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] x = { 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0 }; // n - определяется как количество узлов минус один.

            //double[] x = { -1.5, -0.75, 0, 0.75, 1.5 };

            double[] coef = GetCoefLagrange(x);

            string exp = GetPolynom(coef, x);

            string simpExp = SimplifyPolynom(exp);

            var defInt = GetDefInt(GetSimplifyCoef(simpExp), 0, 1);

            Console.WriteLine("Многочлен Лагранжа:");
            Console.WriteLine(exp);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("Канонический вид:");
            Console.WriteLine(simpExp);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("Определённый интеграл от 0 до 1:");
            Console.WriteLine(defInt);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static double f(double x)
        {
            //return x * x * x * x;
            //return Math.Tan(x);
            return Math.Exp(Math.Pow(x, 1 / 3) * Math.Sin(Math.PI * x)) / (2 + Math.Cos(Math.PI * x));
        }

        static double[] GetCoefLagrange(double[] x)
        {
            int n = x.Length - 1;

            double[] a = new double[n + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
            {
                double den = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j)
                    {
                        den *= (x[i] - x[j]);
                    }
                }

                a[i] = f(x[i]) / den;
            }

            return a;
        }

        static string GetPolynom(double[] a, double[] x)
        {
            string exp = "";
            int n = x.Length - 1;
            var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] < 0) { exp += "("; }
                exp += a[i].ToString(culture);
                if (a[i] < 0) { exp += ")"; }
                for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
                {
                    if (j != i)
                    {
                        exp += "*(x - ";
                        if (x[j] < 0) { exp += "("; }
                        exp += x[j].ToString(culture);
                        if (x[j] < 0) { exp += ")"; }
                        exp += ")";
                    }
                }
                if (i != n) { exp += " + "; }
            }

            return exp;
        }

        static string SimplifyPolynom(string exp)
        {
            return Infix.Format(Algebraic.Expand(Infix.ParseOrUndefined(exp)));
        }

        static double[] GetSimplifyCoef(string exp)
        {
            string[] membr = exp.Split(" + ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            double[] coef = new double[membr.Count() + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < membr.Count(); i++)
            {
                string str = membr[i].Split("*".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].Replace('.', ',');
                string xPow = (membr[i].Split("*".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length > 1)? membr[i].Split("*".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1] : "";
                int pow = 0;
                if (!xPow.Contains('x')) { pow = 0; }
                if (xPow == "x") { pow = 1; }
                if (xPow.Contains('x') && xPow != "x") { pow = int.Parse(xPow[xPow.Length - 1].ToString()); }
                if (str.Contains("("))
                {
                    str = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);
                    coef[pow] = Math.Round(double.Parse(str), 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    coef[pow] = Math.Round(double.Parse(str), 2);
                }
                pow++;
            }
            return coef;
        }

        static double GetDefInt(double[] A, double from, double to)
        {
            string str = "";
            var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            for (int i = 0; i < A.Count(); i++)
            {
                str += (A[i] / (i + 1)).ToString(culture) + "*x^" + (i + 1);
                if (i != A.Count() - 1) { str += " + "; }
            }
            var exp = Infix.ParseOrUndefined(str);
            var x = new Dictionary<string, FloatingPoint> { { "x", 0.0 } };
            var resFrom = Evaluate.Evaluate(x, exp);
            x = new Dictionary<string, FloatingPoint> { { "x", 1.0 } };
            var resTo = Evaluate.Evaluate(x, exp).RealValue;
            return resTo - resFrom.RealValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод консоли:

```
Многочлен Лагранжа:
(-8.68055555555555)*(x - 0.2)*(x - 0.4)*(x - 0.6)*(x - 0.8)*(x - 1) + 83.4365435984129*(x - 0)*(x - 0.4)*(x - 0.6)*(x - 0.8)*(x - 1) + (-291.931019062828)*(x - 0)*(x - 0.2)*(x - 0.6)*(x - 0.8)*(x - 1) + 398.628301975219*(x - 0)*(x - 0.2)*(x - 0.4)*(x - 0.8)*(x - 1) + (-196.79094312252)*(x - 0)*(x - 0.2)*(x - 0.4)*(x - 0.6)*(x - 1) + 26.0416666666667*(x - 0)*(x - 0.2)*(x - 0.4)*(x - 0.6)*(x - 0.8)
---------------------
Канонический вид:
0.333333333333333 + 1.2551290418413*x + (-0.40261625087755)*x^2 + 13.5213484261595*x^3 + (-24.4111890498517)*x^4 + 10.7039944993951*x^5
---------------------
Определённый интеграл от 0 до 1:
1,108
```

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим (на примере PHP), как можно добиться результата без подключения внешних библиотек.

Полином Лагранжа представляет собой сумму частичных полиномов **L<sub>k</sub>(x)**, каждый из которых обращается в нуль во всех узлах, кроме узла с индексом `k`. Коэффициенты **a<sub>k</sub>** при частичных полиномах принято записывать в виде отношения **y<sub>k</sub> / P<sub>k</sub>(x<sub>k</sub>)**, причём **y<sub>k</sub>** - значение полинома в этом узле.

Коэффициентами каждого из частичных полиномов Лагранжа являются значения симметрических полиномов в узлах, для вычисления которых можно написать короткую рекурсивную функцию `get_symm($ar, $k)`.

В дальнейшей работе можно опираться на функцию `poly($ar, $factor)`, в которой обработка одномерного массива `$ar` зависит от типа параметра $factor:

1. Если это число с плавающей точкой, то массив `$ar` на него умножается.
2. Если это такой же одномерный массив, то элементы этих массивов перемножаются.
3. Если `$factor` - это двумерный массив с той же "внешней" размерностью, что и массив `$ar`, то вычисляется линейная комбинация его одномерных массивов,  коэффициенты которой берутся из массива `$ar`.
4. Если `$factor` - это целое число, то вычисляются коэффициенты частичного полинома Лагранжа с таким индексом.
5. А если `$factor` - строка, то она задаёт функцию над массивом `$ar`.

Реализованы следующие функции:

1. `'symmetric'`. Вычисление массива значений всех возможных симметрических полиномов, образуемых числами массива `$ar`.
2. `'denominators'`. Вычисление массива из всех знаменателей P<sub>k</sub>(x<sub>k</sub>).
3. `'degrees'`. Вычисление квадратной матрицы, образованной степенями точек массива.
4. `'reduced'`. Вычисление коэффициентов полинома по его корням.
5. Пользовательская функция над массивом `$ar`, заданная вне функции `poly().`

Перечень опций с примерами выводится в начале работы программы. Такой подход, помимо решения и тестирования поставленной задачи, даёт удобный инструмент для расширения функциональности (интегрирование и дифференцирование полиномов, представление данных и т.д.).

Программа на PHP:

```
$points = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0];
$coeffs = [-8.68, 83.44, -291.93, 398.63, -196.79, 26.04];

function print_m($text, $arr, $level=0){
    $space = str_repeat("&emsp;", $level++);
    echo "$space<b>$text</b>";
    if(gettype($arr)!="array"){
        var_dump($arr);
        return;
    } 
    $flag = false;
    foreach($arr as $value) $flag = $flag || (gettype($value)=="array");
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(gettype($value) != "array") {
            echo $flag ? "<br>$key => $value" : "&emsp;$value";
        } else {
            print_m("<br>$space$key => [", $value, $level);
            echo "&emsp;]";
        }
    }
    $level--;
}

function get_symm($arr, $k){    // $k-th symmetric polynomial of $arr 
    if($k==1) return array_sum($arr);
    $el = array_shift($arr);    // Shifting of the first value from array
    $cnt = count($arr);
    return  ($cnt == 1) ? ($el*end($arr)):
            ($cnt == $k-1) ? ($el*get_symm($arr, $k-1)):
            $el * get_symm($arr, $k-1) + (get_symm($arr, $k));
}

function squares($a){
    return $a * $a;
}

function round8($a){
    return round($a, 8);
}

function poly($ar, $factor = ""){

    switch (gettype($factor)) {

        case 'float':       
        case 'double':              // factoring
            return array_map(function($val)use($factor){ return $val * $factor;}, $ar);     
        case 'array':
            if(!is_array(end($factor))){    // arrays factoring
                return array_map(function($a, $b){return $a * $b;}, $ar, $factor);
            } else {                        // weighted sum of $factor
                $sum = array_fill(0, count($ar), 0.0);  // sum initialization
                array_map(function($a, $ff)use(&$sum){
                    $f = poly($ff, $a);     // array factoring  
                    array_walk($f, function($val, $key)use(&$sum){$sum[$key] += $val;}); // summation 
                }, $ar, $factor);
                return $sum;
            }
        case 'integer':             // k-th Lagrange polynomial by roots
            unset($ar[$factor]);
            return poly($ar, 'reduced');

        case 'string':  
            switch ($factor) {
                case 'symmetric':   // all symmetric polynomials's values
                    return array_map(function($a)use($ar){return get_symm($ar, $a);}, range(1,count($ar)));
                case 'denominators':
                    $prod = []; // prod initialization
                    array_walk($ar, function($value, $key)use($ar, &$prod){
                        $p = 1;
                        array_walk($ar, function($val, $k)use($value, $key, &$p){
                            if($k != $key) $p *= $value - $val;
                        });
                        $prod[] = $p;
                    });
                    return $prod; 
                case 'degrees':     // degrees in accordance with the point quantity
                    $cnt = count($ar);
                    $degree = array_fill(0, $cnt, 1.0);
                    $degrees = [$degree];
                    while(count($degrees) < $cnt) $degrees[] = ($degree = poly($degree, $ar));
                    return $degrees;                    
                case 'reduced':     // all reduced polynomial's coefficients by roots
                    return array_merge(array_reverse(poly(poly($ar, -1.0),"symmetric")),[1.0]);                 
                default:
                    return array_map($factor, $ar);
            }

        default:
            return $arr;
    }
}

$test = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
$results[] = ["Testing points (in float point form) are:&emsp;\$test " => $test];
$results[] = ["Array's factoring:&emsp;poly(\$test, 5.0) " => poly($test, 5.0)];
$results[] = ["Multiplying to 1d array:&emsp; poly(\$test, array_reverse(\$test)) " => poly($test, array_reverse($test))];
$results[] = ["Symmetric polynomials calculation:&emsp; poly(\$test, 'symmetric') " => poly($test, 'symmetric')];
$results[] = ["Lagrange denominators calculation:&emsp; poly(\$test, 'denominators') " => poly($test, 'denominators')];
$results[] = ["Square matrix of degrees: &emsp; \$degrees = poly(\$test, 'degrees') <br>" => $degrees = poly($test, 'degrees')];
$results[] = ["2d array weighting via scalar production: &emsp; poly(\$test, \$degrees)" 
        => poly($test, $degrees)];
$results[] = ["Reduced polynomials via its roots:&emsp; poly(\$test, 'reduced') " => poly($test, 'reduced')];
$results[] = ["User function appying:&emsp; poly(\$test, 'squares') " => poly($test, 'squares')];
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    $results[] = ["Lagrange partial polynomials:&emsp; poly(\$test, $key) " => poly($test, $key)];
}
print_m("<mark>Poly Functions Description:</mark><br>", $results);

$symp[] = ["Lagrange Polynomial's Nodes " => $points];
$symp[] = ["Lagrange Partial Polynomials' Coefficients " => $coeffs];
$parts = [];
foreach ($points as $key =>$value){
    $part = poly($points, $key);
    $parts[] = $part;
    $symp[] = ["Lagrange Partial Polynomial \#$key " => $part];
}
$lagrange = poly($coeffs, $parts);
$symp[] = ["Lagrange Polynomial's Coefficients " => poly($lagrange, 'round8')];
print_m("<br><br><mark>Lagrange Polynomial Symplifying:</mark><br>", $symp);

$denoms = poly($points, 'denominators');
$checking[] = ["Lagrange Denominators " => $denoms];
$values = poly(poly($coeffs, $denoms), 'round8');
$checking[] = ["Polynomial's Values In The Nodes Via Denominators" => $values];
$degrees = poly($points, 'degrees');
$checking[] = ["Degrees of issue Points " => $degrees];
$values2 = poly(poly($lagrange, $degrees), 'round8');
$checking[] = ["Polynomial's Values In The Nodes Via Symplified Polinomial" => $values2];
print_m("<br><br><mark>Checking:</mark><br>", $checking);
```

Результаты:

```
Poly Functions Description:
 
0 => [  
 Testing points (in float point form) are: $test => [ 1 2 3 4 ] ] 
1 => [  
 Array's factoring: poly($test, 5.0) => [ 5 10 15 20 ] ] 
2 => [  
 Multiplying to 1d array:  poly($test, array_reverse($test)) => [ 4 6 6 4 ] ] 
3 => [  
 Symmetric polynomials calculation:  poly($test, 'symmetric') => [ 10 35 50 24 ] ] 
4 => [  
 Lagrange denominators calculation:  poly($test, 'denominators') => [ -6 2 -2 6 ] ] 
5 => [  
 Square matrix of degrees:   $degrees = poly($test, 'degrees') 
=> [   
  0 => [ 1 1 1 1 ]   
  1 => [ 1 2 3 4 ]   
  2 => [ 1 4 9 16 ]   
  3 => [ 1 8 27 64 ] ] ] 
6 => [  
 2d array weighting via scalar production:   poly($test, $degrees) => [ 10 49 142 313 ] ] 
7 => [  
 Reduced polynomials via its roots:  poly($test, 'reduced') => [ 24 -50 35 -10 1 ] ] 
8 => [  
 User function appying:  poly($test, 'squares') => [ 1 4 9 16 ] ] 
9 => [  
 Lagrange partial polynomials:  poly($test, 0) => [ -24 26 -9 1 ] ] 
10 => [  
 Lagrange partial polynomials:  poly($test, 1) => [ -12 19 -8 1 ] ] 
11 => [  
 Lagrange partial polynomials:  poly($test, 2) => [ -8 14 -7 1 ] ] 
12 => [  
 Lagrange partial polynomials:  poly($test, 3) => [ -6 11 -6 1 ] ]

Lagrange Polynomial Symplifying:
 
0 => [  
 Lagrange Polynomial's Nodes => [ 0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1 ] ] 
1 => [  
 Lagrange Partial Polynomials' Coefficients => [ -8.68 83.44 -291.93 398.63 -196.79 26.04 ] ] 
2 => [  
 Lagrange Partial Polynomial \#0 => [ -0.0384 0.4384 -1.8 3.4 -3 1 ] ] 
3 => [  
 Lagrange Partial Polynomial \#1 => [ -0 0.192 -1.232 2.84 -2.8 1 ] ] 
4 => [  
 Lagrange Partial Polynomial \#2 => [ -0 0.096 -0.856 2.36 -2.6 1 ] ] 
5 => [  
 Lagrange Partial Polynomial \#3 => [ -0 0.064 -0.624 1.96 -2.4 1 ] ] 
6 => [  
 Lagrange Partial Polynomial \#4 => [ -0 0.048 -0.488 1.64 -2.2 1 ] ] 
7 => [  
 Lagrange Partial Polynomial \#5 => [ -0 0.0384 -0.4 1.4 -2 1 ] ] 
8 => [  
 Lagrange Polynomial's Coefficients => [ 0.333312 1.256224 -0.4096 13.538 -24.428 10.71 ] ]

Checking:
 
0 => [  
 Lagrange Denominators => [ -0.0384 0.00768 -0.00384 0.00384 -0.00768 0.0384 ] ] 
1 => [  
 Polynomial's Values In The Nodes Via Denominators => [ 0.333312 0.6408192 1.1210112 1.5307392 1.5113472 0.999936 ] ] 
2 => [  
 Degrees of issue Points => [   
  0 => [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]   
  1 => [ 0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1 ]   
  2 => [ 0 0.04 0.16 0.36 0.64 1 ]   
  3 => [ 0 0.008 0.064 0.216 0.512 1 ]   
  4 => [ 0 0.0016 0.0256 0.1296 0.4096 1 ]   
  5 => [ 0 0.00032 0.01024 0.07776 0.32768 1 ] ] ] 
3 => [  
 Polynomial's Values In The Nodes Via Symplified Polinomial => [ 0.333312 0.6408192 1.1210112 1.5307392 1.5113472 0.999936 ] ]
```